# ActiveMQ embedded broker SSL

Tags: grails, ssl, activemq-classic

I'm trying to set up an embedded ActiveMQ broker supporting SSL.

Im continuously getting the same error msg:

```
ActiveMQ Transport Server: ssl://localhost:61613, called closeSocket()
2012-05-04 12:53:11,961 [ActiveMQ Transport Server: ssl://localhost:61613] ERROR          broker.TransportConnector  - Could not accept connection : No available certificate or key corresponds to the SSL cipher suites which are enabled.
```

Searching on this gives indication of possibly malfunction in generating the keystore and truststore.

I have tried to generate the keystore and truststore using these guides without success.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#CreateKeystore

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html

Im trying to set this up in grails and im defining the embeddedActiveMq inside conf/spring/resources.groovy like follows:

```
SpringSslContext sslContext = new SpringSslContext()
    FileSystemResource keyStoreResource = new FileSystemResource("/path/to/keyStore")
    FileSystemResource trustStoreResource = new FileSystemResource("/path/to/trustStore")
    sslContext.setKeyStore(keyStoreResource)
    sslContext.setKeyStorePassword("password")
    sslContext.setTrustStore(trustStoreResource)
    sslContext.setTrustStorePassword("trustword")


    SslBrokerService broker = new SslBrokerService()
    broker.setBrokerName("broker")
    broker.setPersistent(true)
    broker.setUseJmx(true)
    broker.setSslContext(sslContext)

TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector
connector.setUri(new("ssl://localhost:61613"))
broker.addConnector(connector)
broker.start()
```

I cant really get any other valuble debugging information then using

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl,handshake,data,trustmanager,keymanager")
```

Could there be an issue of that java is still trying to use the certificate files in jre6/lib/security?

Is there something specific you need to do in order to get the keystore etc to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ActiveMQ unit tests, especially [SslBrokerServiceTest](https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-unit-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/tcp/SslBrokerServiceTest.java#L59).
It shows how to configure SslBrokerService correctly and how to create `KeyStore` and `TrustStore`.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided above (http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html) actually put a reference to a trouble shooting guide for your issue at [Thawte](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO10061). Go through those steps and verify if you get it working.

Another clue, that might be a long shot, but anyway - when I have had problems with certificates in Java (mostly DSA certificates though -**ensure you have RSA certificates for less trouble**), the JVM installed had export restrictions to certain ciphers. Here is a link to "patch" that. I don't think this will be the case for you, but anyway, might be an idea to check.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-6-download-429243.html